# make checkboxes in springboot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jsp

I want to have some checkboxes in springboot 2.0.0. here what I've written:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class AdminController {
@RequestMapping(value = {"/admin/questionForm"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initForm(Model model) {
    QuestionForm questionForm = new QuestionForm();
    model.addAttribute("questionForm", questionForm);
    List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
    types.add("yes/no");
    types.add("Checkbox with multiple selection");
    types.add("Radio buttons");
    model.addAttribute("types", types);
    return "questionForm";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(Model model, QuestionForm questionForm,
                         BindingResult result) {
    model.addAttribute("questionForm", questionForm);
    return "ProductList";
}
}
```

and in QuestionForm.class i have defined two properties:

```
private boolean newQuestion;

private List<String> types;
```

and this is the questionForm.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<title>Ask</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Ask a Question</h2>

<form:form method="POST" commandName="questionForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Is this a new Question?</td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="newQuestion" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Which type is your question?</td>
            <td><form:checkboxes path="types" items="${types}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Now the question is:**

Why it doesn't show questionForm.jsp when I go to `http://localhost:8080/admin/questionForm`?

This is the error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>       This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>       Sat Feb 23 11:35:14 IRST 2019
>       There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>       Error resolving template "questionForm", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: did you configure view as jsp in application.properties file?

Comment: yeh.. i've added spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp to the application.properties file